# ksoap2 response 404 on android application

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

We have a soap web service in our company and it is reachable from desktop browser and Soap-UI, but wen calling the web service from our android application, we get 404! Does anyone has idea why this is happening?

Our application was OK but the network team made some changes and now the don't accept the responsibility

```
String SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION_PART_ONE + METHOD_NAME;

        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo propInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo1.setType(String.class);
        propInfo1.setName("userName");
        propInfo1.setValue(userName);
        request.addProperty(propInfo1);

        PropertyInfo propInfo2 = new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo2.setType(String.class);
        propInfo2.setName("password");
        propInfo2.setValue(password);
        request.addProperty(propInfo2);


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

            //Get the response
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            return ScanSoapObject(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AuthenticateUserResponse authenticateUserResponse = new AuthenticateUserResponse();
            ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();
            errorModel.setCode(-10);
            errorModel.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.no_connection_to_server));
            authenticateUserResponse.setErrorModel(errorModel);
            return authenticateUserResponse;
        }
```

Comment: does your call require username and password authentication. i did a normal http get call with Authenticator and parsed the xml result myself. Not sure if that is the case with you. i had a similar problem

Comment: Yes, username and password is required. this code was working as a charm for two years! but after network team reconfiguration, the code doesn't work. But it is that the Soap-UI can call the web-service correctly

Comment: use authenticator and try. do a normal http get call you should get the response in xml which you can parse in any way

Comment: Webservice url is http